# Sorting of links with numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, numbers, excel-formula

I have a list of similiar links of website with equal base in Excel. At the and of the link there is numbers, e.g. *_100, *_1013, *_14 and so on.

I need to sort the list descending like

```
*_1013
*_100
*_14
```

(first 4-digit links, then 3-digit, then 2-digit)

Is there any possibility in Excel to sort this array in right way?

Comment: You could sort a specific cell region in excel.  So if all the content starts the same and then each _#### is different, I would start by sorting descending the entire list.  Then do a search for lengths of each string (largest, medium, smallest kind of thing). That's how you grab your 4-digit, 3-digit, and 2-digit lists.  Then sort them individually in Ascending order. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question the `"*_XXX"` is at the end of the string. So to get the values you need to

1. Indentify where the `*_` occurs and extract that
2. Remove the `*-` from the extracted string (which I used `SUBSTITUTE` to do), then convert it to a value

`=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*_",A1)-1),"*_","")),"no match")`

[image]

Comment: +1 nicely explained.  Note that IFERROR is Excel 2007 onward.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an extra column you can extract the number, make it a real number with =value() and then simply sort largest to smallest. (note: prepending 0s, if any exist, would be lost during call to value function)